# How to add listener to element while dragging in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

Is there a way how to add listener "droppable" to element, which is actually hovered while dragging "draggable" element?

I've tried this, but it does not work.

```
$("#draggable span.item").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var pos = ui.position;
    var element = document.elementFromPoint(pos.left, pos.top);

      $(element).droppable({
        classes: {
          "ui-droppable-hover": "hover"
        },
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          console.log('dropped');
        }
      });

  }
});
```

I am trying this because I need apply "droppable" to many elements and classic way via jQuery `$("#droppable span.item").droppable();` is very slow in this case. So I would like to init "droppable" listener only for elements, which are hovered while dropping.

Comment: create snippet/demo with related (html,css,js) code

Comment: add `live: true` to draggable...Please see [link](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-bind-the-droppable-event-to-dynamically-created-nodes)

Comment: @combo_ci `live` is not a valid configuration option for `draggable`: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I've created little demo - https://jsfiddle.net/w5rd3p0w/3/ . First, drag element A and try drop it over element B, nothing happend. When you try i again, it returns alert('dropped'). Because element B has "droppable" ability now, which was given to it by mouseenter or mouseover or mousemove. I need to be alert('droopped') returned while the first drag-try, so I need to add "droppable" ability to element B while I dragging element A and hover with it over element B. Is it possible?Just to be clear, I am trying this solution because I have many elements B in my app and initialize them is slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    did you try this 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $dragging = null;

    $(document.body).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if ($dragging) {
            $dragging.offset({
                top: e.pageY,
                left: e.pageX
            });
        }
    });

    $(document.body).on("mousedown", "div", function (e) {
        $dragging = $(e.target);
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        $dragging = null;
    });
});
```